# How to limit parquet file dimension for a parquet table in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, parquet

I'm trying to create a parquet table in hive.
I can create it but when i run analyze table mytable compute statistics;
i get this result:

numfiles=800, numrows=10000000, totalSize=18909876 rawDataSize=40000000

Why the table is made-up of 800 file for only 180 Mb?
There is a why to set the number of file?
I try with SET parquet.block.size=134217728 but the result is the same

Comment: Question: how many Mappers / Reducers in the job that created the table? If you have 800 Mappers and no Reducer and the properties `hive.merge.***files` are not *True* then you will have 800 physical files. End of story.

Comment: Question: did you check the number of distinct `INPUT__FILE__NAME` in your table? And the the number of HDFS files in the folder used by the table (could be higher because of empty data files)?

Comment: How did you load the table.?

Comment: @ruby @ Samson Scharfrichter I'm using a JavaHiveContext with spark where i put my hiveql query.   I create the table using "create table myTable(.....) stored as parquetfile" and after i create few object that i put in a RDD. I save this RDD like tmp table and next i call a INSERT INTO.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter i have 800 distinct INPUT__FILE__NAME. How could i check the number of HDFS files in the folder used by the table?

Comment: It's due to output written from spark is distributed, May be you need to collect before save it to tmp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number of reducers determines number of parquet files.

Check `mapred.reduce.tasks` parameter.

E.g. you may have a map-reduce job that produces just 100 rows, but if `mapred.reduce.tasks` is set to 800 (explicitly or implicitly), you'll have 800 parquet files as output (most of parquet files will have only headers and no actual data).

Comment: True. Before i was submitting my spark application with 6 executor on 8 core each one and it produced 800 job. Now i try with only one core on the driver and i get only 10 file (and 10 job).  It's ok but how can i get only 10 file using all my resources?

Comment: So it can be selected as the right answer. Each reducer has to produce its own output (parquet) file. You can still have required number of mappers and play with number of reducers to see a good balance between time to create parquet file and time to read it, depending on what's more important for your case.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to set set dfs.blocksize=134217728 along with
SET parquet.block.size=134217728
Both the block size should be set while doing hive insert.

Comment: I try but the result is the same